# Bind to static generic instance of a class

Tags: wpf, generics, binding, singleton, static-classes

I use this code in my views' (which are `UserControl`) constructors:

```
this.DataContext = The<Chart1ViewModel>.Instance;
```

Where the `The<>` is a generic **static** per-type singleton storage which also **needs to** implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` to notify of it's instance replacement.

I would like to XAML this code like, how can I do that? I have never before did bind anything to a generic static classes.

If I can't, how could I create a `Binding` to that static class' `Instance` property?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know you'll have problems using generics in XAML. Nevertheless you can use static classes. By wrapping a property around the generic you could do something like this:

```
<Control DataContext="{x:Static The.Chart1ViewModel.Instance}" />
```

Comment: The thing is there can be an unknown type, not just the `Chart1ViewModel`.

Comment: You would need several new properties then. You could also check a way to use generics in XAML but I haven't gain experience with that so far: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee956431.aspx